# Grails application not running with filters

Tags: grails, spring-security

I’m trying to add filters to application. There are lots of information about filters, including official Spring Security Plugin: http://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/2.0.x/guide/single.html#filters . Also I found a simple example: https://www.djamware.com/post/58a53b5180aca748640ce350/securing-rest-api-with-grails-3-and-spring-security-rest .

My first idea was: something wrong with my version of grails or security plugin… But I have errors each time when adding filters on any version! I tried Grails 2.4.3, 2.5*, 3.3.6. Same with spring seciruty core plugin.

Adding any filter chain, for example:

```
grails.plugin.springsecurity.filterChain.chainMap = [
  [pattern: '/api/**', filters:'JOINED_FILTERS,-anonymousAuthenticationFilter,-exceptionTranslationFilter,-authenticationProcessingFilter,-securityContextPersistenceFilter'],
  [pattern: '/**', filters:'JOINED_FILTERS,-restTokenValidationFilter,-restExceptionTranslationFilter']
]
```

Error for Grails v3.3.6

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/context/embedded/FilterRegistrationBean
        at grails.plugin.springsecurity.SpringSecurityCoreGrailsPlugin$_doWithSpring_closure12.doCall(SpringSecurityCoreGrailsPlugin.groovy:204)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1427)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:98)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.metaclass.ClosureMetaClass.invokeMethod(ClosureMetaClass.java:264)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1034)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:418)
        at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:412)
        at grails.spring.BeanBuilder.invokeBeanDefiningClosure(BeanBuilder.java:759)
        at grails.spring.BeanBuilder.beans(BeanBuilder.java:588)
        at grails.spring.BeanBuilder.invokeMethod(BeanBuilder.java:531)
        at org.grails.plugins.DefaultGrailsPlugin.doWithRuntimeConfiguration(DefaultGrailsPlugin.java:559)
        at org.grails.plugins.AbstractGrailsPluginManager.doRuntimeConfiguration(AbstractGrailsPluginManager.java:167)
        at grails.boot.config.GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(GrailsApplicationPostProcessor.groovy:171)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:272)
        at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:122)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:687)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:525)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:84)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:393)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp.run(GrailsApp.groovy:380)
        at grails.boot.GrailsApp$run.call(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:116)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:136)
        at mysecurerest.Application.main(Application.groovy:8)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 34 common frames omitted
```

Error for Grails 2.4.3

```
ERROR context.GrailsContextLoaderListener  - Error initializing the application: No signature of method: SpringSecurityCoreGrailsPlugin$_closure4_closure56.doCall() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap) values: [[pattern:/api/**, filters:JOINED_FILTERS,-anonymousAuthenticationFilter,-exceptionTranslationFilter,-authenticationProcessingFilter,-securityContextPersistenceFilter]]
Possible solutions: doCall(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object), call(), call([Ljava.lang.Object;), call(java.lang.Object), call(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object), findAll()
Message: No signature of method: SpringSecurityCoreGrailsPlugin$_closure4_closure56.doCall() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap) values: [[pattern:/api/**, filters:JOINED_FILTERS,-anonymousAuthenticationFilter,-exceptionTranslationFilter,-authenticationProcessingFilter,-securityContextPersistenceFilter]]
Possible solutions: doCall(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object), call(), call([Ljava.lang.Object;), call(java.lang.Object), call(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object), findAll()
    Line | Method
->>  631 | doCall    in SpringSecurityCoreGrailsPlugin$_closure4
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
|    266 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1142 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    617 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread

ERROR Exception sending context initialized event to listener
instance of class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoaderListener
Message: Error executing bootstraps; nested exception is groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: SpringSecurityCoreGrailsPlugin$_closure4_closure56.doCall() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap) values: [[pattern:/api/**, filters:JOINED_FILTERS,-anonymousAuthenticationFilter,-exceptionTranslationFilter,-authenticationProcessingFilter,-securityContextPersistenceFilter]]
Possible solutions: doCall(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object), call(), call([Ljava.lang.Object;), call(java.lang.Object), call(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object), findAll()
    Line | Method
->>  266 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
|   1142 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    617 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run       in java.lang.Thread
Caused by MissingMethodException: No signature of method: SpringSecurityCoreGrailsPlugin$_closure4_closure56.doCall() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.LinkedHashMap) values: [[pattern:/api/**, filters:JOINED_FILTERS,-anonymousAuthenticationFilter,-exceptionTranslationFilter,-authenticationProcessingFilter,-securityContextPersistenceFilter]]
Possible solutions: doCall(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object), call(), call([Ljava.lang.Object;), call(java.lang.Object), call(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object), findAll()
->>  631 | doCall    in SpringSecurityCoreGrailsPlugin$_closure4
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
|    266 | run       in java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
|   1142 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    617 | run       in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    745 | run . . . in java.lang.Thread
```

What am I doing wrong? Or what was missed?

Comment: First of all grails 2 and grails 3 has different supported spring security versions and different config. So you can't try same config on both versions. Could you please provide spring security core version that you used on grails 3?

Comment: I've tried different versions with different combinations grails+scurity-spring-core. Latest examples:

Grails 2.4.3: spring-security-core:2.0-RC4

Grails 3.3.6: org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:3.1.1

Comment: the latest one is 3.2.3(spring security) could you try with that version? https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/3.2.x/index.html#installation

Comment: great! With combination of java 1.8.0.181 (x86) + grails 3.3.6 + org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:3.2.3  I was able to add filters.
my goal is rest authorization, so tried to add rest plugin and stuck with other known issue when /api/login returns 405 (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36399403/405-method-not-allowed-on-api-login-options-request-with-grails-spring-security for example)

Comment: but I'm still interested in grails 2.4.3 (as my working project uses this version). I've tried grails 3 just to understand if this is a trouble with grails 2. Is it possible to run grails 2 + security-core + security-rest + filters?

Comment: Thank you a lot, Koloritnij ! I've tried of experiments with different versions. You gave me at least one possible way: try to upgrade project to grails 3!

Comment: You are welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how, but I've got Grails 2 working with filters after Grails 3 issues were fixed!

So my story for solution is:

1. Try different Java, Grails and spring-security-core versions (both 2 and 3).
2. After @Koloritnij suggested to check Grails 3.3.6 + org.grails.plugins:spring-security-core:3.2.3 (runned on java 1.8.0.181) I was able to run Grails 3 project with filters correctly.
3. Go back to my Java 1.8.0.25 + Grails 2.4.3 + spring-security-core:2.0.0 and it works!